# assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]gcc

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

buenas, estoy arrancando en la programacion C y me topo con un error que no sabria saber que es o como solucionarlo, si alguno me puede dar una mano lo agradeceria un monton.
El error me aparece en la linea que esta `l_agregar(lista, random)` y el error es

> assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
> [-Wint-conversion]gcc

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "listas.h"
#include "tipo_elemento.h"
#include "lista_cursores.c"
#include "tipo_elemento.c"

Lista cargaAlAzar(Lista lista)
{
    TipoElemento random = te_crear(0);
    srand(time(NULL));
    // Cargar datos aleatorios en la lista
    for (int i = 0; i < TAMANIO_MAXIMO; i++)
    {
        random = rand() % 100;
        l_agregar(lista, random);
    }

    l_mostrarLista(lista);

    return lista;
}

int main()
{
    Lista lista = l_crear();
    cargaAlAzar(lista);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor comparte el código de la función `l_agregar` y lo que sea necesario para poder identificar la causa del problema. También ayudará que incluyas el error completo

Comment: `assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]gcc`Indica que al asignar un valor entero a un puntero sin convertirlo explícitamente, no compila
por ese motivo.